# Where is iCloud KV data stored on the filesystem?

Tags: icloud, filesystems

I need to do some debugging, and need to read and modify values stored on [iCloud Key-Value](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForKey-ValueDataIniCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH7-SW1) storage for my app (using `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`. Does anybody know where this is stored on disk, and what format it is in (some sort of database, json, etc)? I know containers are stored in the equivalently named folder in Library, and documents are stored in `Mobile Documents`, but what about iCloud KV data?